# Python : Can Dictionary be used for indexing?

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

This is my first question on StackOverflow and I have searched so many websites but couldn't find what I was looking for (or didn't notice). Please do not discourage me :)

Also, This is my first programming experience with Python and I'm confused.

I have a text file and it has 3 columns inside separated with WhiteSpaces. These columns are `DeptID`, `CourseID`, `NumberofStudentsEnrolled`.

Here is the sample data:

```
101 10001 23
102 10002 30
102 10004 5
102 10005 13
105 10006 59
105 10007 77
```

So, whenever I call `DeptID` indices and `CourseID` indices, the program will give me the number of students enrolled.

Example : `NumberofEnrolled("101","10001")` should give `23` as answer.

Should I try matrices instead? Because I'm kind of lost. I know what I want, but I don't know what it is called in `Python`.

```
import numpy

depts = []
courses = []

file = open("C:\\Info.txt", "r")

# SPLIT EVERY LINE INTO 3 PIECES : DeptID , CourseID , Enrolled
for line in file:
    depts.append(line.split()[0]) # ADD Depts
    courses.append(line.split()[1])  # ADD Courses

# CLOSE THE FILE
file.close()  

# I HAVE TRIED NUMPY BUT COULDN'T HANDLE WITH IT.
numpyList = numpy.zeros((57, 57), dtype = numpy.int32)    

dept_array = numpy.array(dept)
course_array = numpy.array(course)


test_dict = {}
for i in range(len(dept_array)):
test_dict[dept_array[i]] = course_array[i]
```

test_dict output is:

```
{'101': '10001', '102': '10005', '105': '10007'}
```

This output takes only last data for multiple data. I guess I need a type that can hold multiple pairs inside.

Comment: I'd recommend looking into `dataframes` and `pandas`

Comment: Can't i use numpy for this?

Comment: this can easily be done with a dictionary of dictionaries, you don't necessarily need heavyweight (`numpy` or `pandas`) solutions

Answer (score 7):

You can easily read your data into a dictionary of dictionaries:

```
data = {}
for line in file:
    dept, course, num_students = line.split()
    data.setdefault(dept, {})[course] = int(num_students)
```

Now you can lookup:

```
>>> data["101"]["10001"]
23
```

Answer (score 3):

Others have given you some options.

I would offer that since the pair (deptID, courseID) is bound to be unique you could use tuples as your key.

```
depts = dict()

depts[(101,10001)] = 23
depts[(102,10002)] = 30
depts[(102,10004)] = 5
depts[(102,10005)] = 13
depts[(105,10006)] = 59
depts[(105,10007)] = 77


print(depts)
#output: {(102, 10002): 30, (101, 10001): 23, (105, 10006): 59, (102, 10005): 13, (105, 10007): 77, (102, 10004): 5}

print(depts.keys())
#output: [(102, 10002), (101, 10001), (105, 10006), (102, 10005), (105, 10007), (102, 10004)]

#should you ever need to access all the courses associated with an ID you 
#can use a filter with a lambda or more easily a List Comprehension
#to identify that data.  But this will be have O(n) time look up as opposed
#to a dictionary of dictionaries which would have a O(1) look up for 
#associated courseID lookups.
print([catalogue[1] for catalogue in depts.keys() if catalogue[0] == 102])
#output: [10002, 10005, 10004]


for (i,j) in depts.keys() :
    print (depts[(i,j)])
#output:   30
#output:   23
#output:   59
#output:   13
#output:   77
#output:   5
```

Comment: I am sorry but i am new in Phyton :)
So can i do something like 
 `depts[(i, j)]`

Comment: There's nothing to apologize for bud.  If you expect to use python more in the future you may want to pick up a copy of the python cookbook by Oreilly.  It's helped a lot of people, and in my opinion is a fairly good read.

Comment: Thank you @FredMan. 
can i do something like depts[(i, j)] ?

Comment: Definitely.  Set i to some variable and j to some variable and then call depts[(i,j)] and it'll find the student count.  I'll edit my post to have an example.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

It will easy if you convert your data into a dictionary.

Open your info.txt file and save as info.csv. The reason for this is, because csv can easily handle spaces or commas and any other separators.

```
import csv

data_dict = {}
# you can change the delimiter if its something other than space.
with open("C:\\Info.txt", "r") as fobj:
    data = csv.reader(fobj, delimiter=' ')

    # reading the rows/lines of the file
    for row in data:
        if row[0] in data_dict.keys():
            data_dict[row[0]][row[1]] = row[2]
        else:
            data_dict[row[0]] = {row[1]: row[2]}

def func(dept_id, course_id):
    # check whether the dept_id exists in your current dictonary
    if dept_id in data_dict.keys():
        # check whether the course_id exists in your current dictonary
        if course_id in data_dict[dept_id].keys():
            return data_dict[dept_id][course_id]
        else:
            print ('Invalid course id')
    else:
        print ('invalid department id')

print func('101', '10001')
```

Comment: This is currently wrong, `data_dict[row[0]] = {row[1]: row[2]}` will keep overwriting the value associated with `row[0]` rather than adding new data to it.

Comment: @donkopotamus thank you for pointing that out. I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanna use both DeptID and CourseID, it seems you need a 2-dimensional lookup table (not an actual Python built-in thing) where first looking up maybe the DeptID (in a dictionary) will give you a table (dictionary) of CourseIDs paired with number enrolled that correspond to that Department.

Kinda inefficient, but it also seems to me that all the CourseIDs are gonna be unique, and if so, is it possible for you to just do lookups based on that?